# Get records where today is 6 months after date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to run a query and get all the records where today is 6 months after the start date.

Here is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

```
select * from users where DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = CURDATE()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean 6 or more months after the start date?

Comment: I mean today is 6 months after the start date

Comment: You might have to take some note of dates like "six months after August 31st" where you'll get February 28th four days in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  First, your code is checking for one month rather than 6 months.

The first possibility is that you don't have any records on that date.

Another is that the dates have times associated with them.  If so, you can do:

```
where DATE_ADD(DATE(start_date), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: yea i was just using one month as an example, didnt work with no matter how many months i put in there.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!